# why does TemporaryDirectory change type within a "with" block?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python3 console

```
>>> x1=tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
>>> print(type(x1))
<class 'tempfile.TemporaryDirectory'>
>>> with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as x2:
...   print(type(x2))
... 
<class 'str'>
```

Why is `x1` a `TemporaryDirectory` and `x2` a `str`?

Comment: Read the documentation ... "The directory name can be retrieved from the name attribute of the returned object. When the returned object is used as a context manager, the name will be assigned to the target of the as clause in the with statement, if there is one."

Comment: because `with x() as y` is not the same as `y = x()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `with foo() as x` has `x` take on the value of `foo().__enter__()`'s return value.

`x = foo()` is a different thing.

See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d16c9d1278164f04778861814ebc87ed087511fc/Lib/tempfile.py#L860-L952) for the implementation of `TemporaryDirectory`; it does a bunch of things, but the important thing is that `enter`ing the context manager returns the directory name, and exiting the context manager destroys that named directory.

```
class TemporaryDirectory:
   ...

    def __enter__(self):
        return self.name

   ...
```